# Advantage of NoSQL on saving text data

Tags: nosql

Q1. Why do people often prefer to use NoSQL over RDBMS for storing data like tweets?
Q2. Is there any NoSQL database that supports a SQL-like query syntax?

A sample table for the Q1 would be:

*Status*

- UID
- Status
- Timestamp

Comment: These are two separate questions: please ask them as such. Combining them makes it hard for the SO voting mechanism to evaluate the best answer.  I suggest you keep this question focused on the fitness of NoSQL for textual data and ask a separate question for SQL syntax.

Comment: The answer for Q2 will be just a name only !

Comment: Doesn't matter, it still ought to be a separate question.

Comment: To answer #2 - we've used Google Datastore with great success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSQL databases, especially [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), are often a good choice for storing things like tweets because they offer very quick write speeds, fast querying, and can easily distribute large data sets across a cluster of servers.

Many NoSQL databases have their own query syntax, but some such as [Hive](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive), a data warehouse product built on top of Hadoop, do have SQL-like query languages.

Comment: +1: in which of these NoSQL is faster than RDBMS- > read/write/query/sub-query/join/in-notIn-distinct

Comment: It'd depend on the structure of your data and your access patterns, the best thing to do is try it and see.  NoSQL databases don't tend to support join operations because they don't store data in a relational way.

Answer (score 2):

Q1:

NoSQL products are primarily known for their ability to scale (sharding and replication) and their schema-less design. Twitter uses FlockDB (a graph DB) and not an RDBMS because of that, and because it makes more sense to use graphs to describe who follows who - not because the actual text messages.

Other benefits of NoSQL include advanced querying techniques (Map/Reduce): CouchDB and RavenDB are document-oriented DBs built on top of Lucene, and therefore can offer full-text search queries out-of-the-box, something you could never do efficiently with RDBMS.

Q2:

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net) queries are Linq expressions, which mimics SQL syntax, and is quite identical to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. For unstructured data, or for data
   whose structure is dynamic (i.e. if
   stored in a RDBMS, the table
   structure will continually be
   changed). Imagine storing data about, say films, in a database. You start off with title and director, but before long you realise you also need to save all the actors/actresses, the year --> table structure change. You then want to store similar films --> another change. For such a scenario saving data in key/value pairs may well be easier, as you simply add the new data into the existing structure (though the example you give - basically a BLOB of text - doesn't really fit that description).
2. [Orient](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/SQL) supports SQL-similar syntax

Comment: plz explain a little bit more on Q1